# Use strict is enforced even though it's not present in code

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules, strict

I'm trying to access `function.arguments` in my typescript module but get the error:

`'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions`

Even tho `'use strict'` is not present in the compiled files.

This is my tsconfig.json settings:

```
    "noImplicitUseStrict": true,
    "alwaysStrict": false,
    "strict": true,
```

If I remove `"noImplicitUseStrict": true` the compiled files will have `use strict` so the setting is def working on the typescript side (probly?).

Searching through my compiled files I cannot find a single file containg the word "strict".

I compile the js files using node: `node src/index.js`

Comment: Uh, why would you want to use `function.arguments` when you can just access the `arguments` object directly? (Though in ES6 you'd more likely just use rest parameters anyway)

Comment: Modules and classes are strict. Potentially other places as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ES6 Modules execute in strict mode.

From MDN [Other differences between modules and standard scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#Other_differences_between_modules_and_standard_scripts)

> Also, note that you might get different behavior from sections of
>   script defined inside modules as opposed to in standard scripts. This
>   is because modules use strict mode automatically.